# ClassNotFoundException for TestApp when I start hazelcast/bin/run.bat

Tags: java, hazelcast

I started exploring hazelcast today  I downloaded hazelcast-2.0 from the site, and following the ScreenCast provided in their site. I went to the bin directory and started **run.bat** from the command prompt.

I am getting the `ClassNotFoundException`. Can somebody please let me know what would have went wrong?

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.hazelcast.examples.TestApp  
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)  
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)  
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)  
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)  
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)  
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: That exception usually means that a .class or JAR file is missing from your CLASSPATH.  Either the .bat file is incorrect or there's a JAR missing.

Comment: I have downloaded hazelcast 1.9.4.8 . now this is starting properly!

Comment: I second that, can you post the exact command being issued in your run.bat?  The entire java or java -jar command (alternatively, run the same command from your run.bat file in a command window and post that here)

Comment: java -cp ../lib/hazelcast-${project.version}.jar com.hazelcast.examples.TestApp

Comment: Got it now... somehow the $project.version variable is not getting the value. if i replace it with 2.0 manually, it works fine!

Answer (score 1):

As noted in duffymo's comment, there is a problem in the **.bat** file as it adds the following to the classpath `../lib/hazelcast-${project.version}.jar`.

Just replace `${project.version}` with the version number you downloaded, or check the correct jar name from the lib directory and everything should work properly.

Comment: Thats right.. that means, hazelcast 2.0 is buggy .. i read somewhere saying, 1.9.3 had the same problem and it got fixed in 1.9.4

Comment: I won't say that it is buggy because of that. This is just a build/packaging problem :)

Comment: Yes, this is a packaging problem and will be fixed in 2.0.1 patch release.